# Mvc 3 Printing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, printing

I have a small problem and i was wondering if it can be solved.
I am doing small Mvc 3 app. Everything is ok, but printing is hard to do. I have view for print and inside:

```
    <style type="text/css" media="screen, print">

body {
   moz-transform: scale(.70);
}

page {  

 margin-left: 6mm;  
 margin-right: 6mm;  
 margin-top: 20mm;  
 margin-bottom: 20mm;  
} 

page { size : portrait }
page rotated { size : landscape }
table { page : rotated }


</style>

@(new MvcHtmlString((string)ViewBag.Content))
```

That MvcHtmlString contains everything i need to display nice table on that view. To this point everything is still great :).
My only problem is with printing, i need to set scale to 70 % margins like in css above, but that css above isnt working at all.
I dont want user to put scaling 70 % , margin-left: 6 mm etc,  i want to do i myself so user can just click print a get printout like should.

And the print is looking best at above setting, which i can set in print preview, but can it be done programmaticaly??

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Transform` property is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, and Opera. Internet Explorer 9 supports an alternative, the -ms-transform property.Safari and Chrome support an alternative, the -webkit-transform property.

So you may write something like that:

```
div
{
-moz-transform: rotate(70deg); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: rotate(70deg); /* IE */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(70deg); /* Safari, Chrome, iOS */
    -o-transform: rotate(70deg); /* Opera */
    transform: rotate(70deg);
}
```

`Transform` is CSS3 property. So some old browsers anyway will ignore it. I would recommend just make your print page content smaller without skale factors.

Comment: Ty for your help, based on what you said i think that resizing my view is better then forcing to scale :). Ty for suggestions and help.